# How to set the chartjs bar graph scale to the highest value in the result data

Tags: chart.js

Hi i am using chartjs for the bar graph. i have data like

```
var barData = {
labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
datasets : [
    {
        fillColor : "#48A497",
        strokeColor : "#48A4D1",
        data : [45,47,124,56,70,60]
    }
]
};
```

if we see the data in this highest value is **124** but the scale will show **45** at the highest place. 
how to set is according to highest value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easier workaround to do this. Just add a `null` to the end of your data array, like so

```
var barData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "#48A497",
            strokeColor: "#48A4D1",
            data: [45, 47, 124, 56, 70, 60, null]
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: i am marking it as the answer because It is working fine, but i did not get the logic, how it works. after all good effort, thanks.

Comment: Chart.js uses Maht.min interally to figure out the range of data. Math.min treats null as 0, thereby extending the scale to start from 0. And because there is no label the point is not plotted.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the greatest value from the data and divide it with the **ScaleSteps** and set in **scaleStepWidth** so it becomes custom scale according to my highest value.

```
 var myBarChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("id").getContext("2d")).Bar(BarChart, {
    animation: false,
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 10,
    scaleStartValue: 0,
    scaleStepWidth: 20
});
```

Now the Sacle will be 0 to 200. which is OK for me.

Comment: This is also a way any one can use, it also working perfectly for me.